# C# Best way to ignore exception

Tags: c#, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ignore Exception in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913159/ignore-exception-in-c-sharp)

Sometimes in rare circumstances you really want to just ignore exception. What is the best way to do this? my approach is catch the exception but dont do anything about it. others?

```
                        try
                        {
                            blah
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            <nothing here>
                        }
```

Comment: Hopefully, you just want to ignore one or a few specific exceptions. Ignoring all exceptions is not really a good idea.

Comment: Not Exception. Just the type of the particular exception you want to ignore

Comment: I agree with @BrianRasmussen.  And when you DO ignore an exception, please add a comment explaining WHY you are ignoring it.

Comment: @SteveWellens I do that. My comment is usually: `// don't care` (and the code really ought not to care) :D

Comment: @Steve Nice comment about comments.

Comment: I agree with Brian too, aside from the fact that sometimes when you are calling 3rd party code, you just don't know what exceptions might be thrown (unlike say in Java).

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913159/ignore-exception-in-c-sharp

Comment: @EricPetroelje Except for the dastardly IOException, most of the time one "doesn't know" in Java either ..

Comment: Be careful when leaving exceptions unattended since they are just hiding a harmful situation. I would recommend you to log that the exception was raised and put a comment in the code to clarify that you wanted intentionally to do nothing.

Comment: Here's what I believe is a legitimate use for empty catch clauses. My application creates *.csv files that are displayed to the user. The user can choose to save the *.csv files as an *.xls file or just close it. Before creating the file, I place its FQFN on a stack. When exiting the application, I attempt to delete all the files in the stack. Some may have been deleted by the user, so I'm going to ignore file-not-found, and I know the name is reliable, so I can't imagine getting any other exception.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you are going to just catch, not handle the exception, and ignore it, you can simplify what you have slightly.

```
try
{
   // code
}
catch
{ }
```

The above is for any exception, if you only want to ignore a certain exception but let others bubble out, you can do this

```
try
{
   // code
}
catch (SpecificException)
{ }
```

If you do ignore exceptions like this, it is best to include some comment in the catch block as to why you are ignoring the exception like that.

Comment: As a seasoned developer, I have found this to be asking for trouble. You can end up with exceptions that don't happen all the time and are not reproducible because somewhere along the line, an exception is IGNORED. I think if you don't intend to specifically handle an exception, then you should not catch it. The calling method can catch the exception and decide what to do. Exceptions are passed down the stack.You could rethrow the exception and add some comments like "Failed to Send over network, + " ex.message .. and the calling function can catch this

Comment: There are several situations where you would eat (ignore) the exception. For example you wouldn't want your logging framework to throw exceptions that prevent your business functionality from working. Basically, you don't want your main task to fail just because there might be a problem in optional non-essential code.

Comment: I would add a Logging Entry along the `Info/Warn` Levels for even though i want to ignore and continue, it isn't something that should happen.

Answer (score 9):

```
try
{
    DoBlah();
}
catch { }
```

Comment: I'll add - put a comment in that empty `catch` block to explain *why* you are ignoring the exception.

Comment: This is discouraged by MS best practices.

Comment: @Zarathos - The question isn't about 'best practices', it's about swallowing exceptions.

Comment: If it's discouraged, it's bot the best solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182137.aspx

Comment: There are some cases where, because of design issues with other components, there may not be any good alternative.  If `DoBlah` sometimes throws exceptions that generally represent harmless conditions but doesn't completely document what exceptions might be thrown, and if the caller doesn't care whether the method succeeded or not [its contract with `OtherThing` says it will call `Otherthing.DoBlah`, but the calling code has no reason to care whether it works].

Answer (score 5):

It could be something like this

```
try
{
    //blah
}
catch{}
```

If you want to ignore a specific exception

```
try
{
    //blah
}catch(YourException){}
```