# How to handle exception error 404 not found while downloading files in the backgroundworker completed event?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void downloadFile(IEnumerable<string> urls)
{
    foreach (var url in urls)
    {
        _downloadUrls.Enqueue(url);
    }

    // Starts the download
    btnGetDownload.Text = "Downloading...";
    btnGetDownload.Enabled = false;
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
    lblFileName.Visible = true;

    DownloadFile();
}

private void DownloadFile()
{
    if (_downloadUrls.Any())
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0 Chrome");
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;

        var url = _downloadUrls.Dequeue();
        string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(url);

        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"D:\Videos\videos\" + FileName);
        lblFileName.Text = url;

        return;
    }

    // End of the download
    btnGetDownload.Text = "Download Complete";
}

private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // handle error scenario
        throw e.Error;
    }

    if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        // handle cancelled scenario
    }

    counter--;

    lblFilesCount.Text = counter.ToString();

    DownloadFile();
}

void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    double bytesIn = double.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    double totalBytes = double.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    double percentage = bytesIn / totalBytes * 100;

    progressBar1.Value = int.Parse(Math.Truncate(percentage).ToString());
}

private void btnGetDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    downloadFile(videosLinks);
}
```

After downloading 400 files out of 1500, I got an exception 404 not found in this line :

```
if (e.Error != null)
{
    // handle error scenario
    throw e.Error;
}
```

The application had to be closed.

I want to continue the download to the next file, or maybe to make something that it will try to download the same file let's say more 5 times and then if not found 5 times continue to the next file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Best way to ignore exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14389371/c-sharp-best-way-to-ignore-exception)

Comment: Quite why you are using `WebClient` and `BackgroundWorker` is another question: both are effectively deprecated. You should use `HttpClient` and Tasks and `async` `await` instead.

Comment: + You don't need to create 1500 `WebClient`. Just one, make `client` class variable, move the creation and events hook up lines to the first method `downloadFile(...)`, and dispose of it where you comment `End of the download`.