# How to Continue program on error

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net program that accesses 10 different databases for reports.  I am using a "Try" statement at the end of my program to send the data I build with LINQ from the datasets via email.

The problem i'm running into is when I try to connect to a database that is offline, or times out the program locks up, or ends.  What i'd like to do is something similar to "On error resume Next" however, I can't do that with a try statement already in the program... Any suggestions?

Comment: What language is this in? Are both tags appropriate?

Comment: "I can't do that with a try statement already in the program" - why not use other `try` statements?

Comment: VB.net would be great for now.

Comment: I think what you need is a `catch` statement.

Comment: Catch block with nothing in it...it silences the errors and keeps you trucking along...

Comment: I have the catch statement, but again I have 10 different connections I need to monitor, so if 1 times out, go to 2, if 4 times out go to 5 etc...

Comment: @FrankTudor - That is a horrible practice.

Comment: @Oded It was what the person asked.  We are not re-factoring here...

Comment: But teaching and showing the right way, is.

Answer (score 3):

on error resume next under vb.net;

```
    Try
        something()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'do nothing
    End Try
```

try to find a better way to handle this if this is a long term code / production code

Comment: @Oded, the question is, how to simulate on error resume next and if I remember correctly this is the behavior of vb6

Comment: And yet, showing someone a really bad practice as a solution doesn't sit well with me.

Comment: +1. Yes, it's horribly bad practice, but we shouldn't punish people for answering the question instead of criticizing it.

Comment: @Oded, i added a small note in my answer

Comment: Note that the `ex As Exception` can be omitted, if you don't do anything with `ex`. (Of course, usually you *should* do something with it, even if it is just logging the error.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer on stackoverflow. It is in C# though

[Ignore Exception in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913159/ignore-exception-in-c-sharp)

Basically it is an expression which deals with exceptions on the top level.

However, you have to make sure that you wrap each possible code block with it as exceptions are structured.

Answer (score 0):

Call your database from a seperate function that returns you a boolean on success or not. Somthing like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Try
            'do something or nothing
    If Not OpenConnecttion() Then
    End If
Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception

    Throw
End Try
```

End Sub

```
Private Function OpenConnecttion() As Boolean
        'do you database conenction and maybe retrieval stuff here
Try
Catch ex As Exception
    Return False
End Try
Return True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Fredou's answer is technically correct, I would suggest that you slightly restructure your program. Instead of

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim db1 = OpenDbConnection()        ' fails
...do something with db1...         ' more errors, failing silently, occur here
```

you ensure that only the operation opening the database is allowed to fail:

```
Dim db1 As OleDbConnection          ' or whatever DB library you happen to use
Try
    db1 = OpenDbConnection()
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("Skipping DB1: " & ex.ToString())
End Try

If db1 IsNot Nothing
    ...do something with db1...     ' Errors occuring here *are* reported
End If
```

That way, you are only ignoring errors *in certain well-defined parts of your code*.