# Is it possible to not break execution flow on certain exceptions but break on others - and if so, how?

Tags: c#, exception

I need to call several methods from an external framework - or rather I am writing a wrapper around it for other users to call methods from this framework in a non-predetermined order. Now some methods of the framework will throw exceptions, even though no "real" error occured. Basically they are supposed to be internal exceptions just to notify whoever that the action to be performed has already been performed before. For example: that a file has been loaded. It wont hurt to load the file another time, so for all I care this "error" is no error at all. So I need to continue on this exception, but I also need to catch other, real exceptions, such as when the framework, which connects to clients and stuff, cannot do so.

Below I have some (extremely simplified) example code. Obviously that code wont compile because the code for the custom exceptions is missing. Also in real life the code is spread over three assemblies. This means, that I cannot wrap the exception handler around those framework methods which will throw `InternalFrameworkException()` only. I can only wrap it around the whole `SomeMethod()`. As I wrote, this is an extremely simplified example.

Is there any way to handle the `RealException()s` but continue the `InternalFrameworkException()s` without using [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4913179/810106)? Note that this is not about letting the `InternalFrameworkException()` fall through, but they should actually not break out of the `try{}` block at all.

```
namespace ExceptionTest
{
    using System;

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SomeMethod();
            }
            catch (InternalFrameworkException exception)
            {
                // Do not actually catch it - but also dont break the
                // execution of "SomeMethod()".
                // Actually I never want to end up here...
            }
            catch (RealException exception)
            {
                // Break the execution of SomeMethod() as usual.
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                // Again, break the execution of SomeMethod() as usual.
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Clean up.
            }
        }

        #region == Method is actually contained in another assembly referencing this assembly ===

        private static void SomeMethod()
        {
            // Should break if uncommented.
            // MethodThrowingProperException();
            // Should not break.
            MethodThrowingInternalExceptionOrRatherContinuableError();
            // Should execute, even if previously an internal framework error happened.
            MethodNotThrowingException();
        }

        #endregion

        #region ===== Framework methods, they are contained in a foreign dll =====

        private static void MethodThrowingProperException()
        {
            // Something happened which should break execution of the
            // application using the framework
            throw new RealException();
        }

        private static void MethodThrowingInternalExceptionOrRatherContinuableError()
        {
            // Perform some stuff which might lead to a resumable error,
            // or rather an error which should not break the continuation
            // of the application. I.e. initializing a value which is
            // already initialized. The point is to tell the application using
            // this framework that the value is already initialized, but
            // as this wont influence the execution at all. So its rather
            // a notification.
            throw new InternalFrameworkException();
        }

        private static void MethodNotThrowingException()
        {
            // Well, just do some stuff.
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Edit: I did try the example in the post I already [linked above](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/), and it works like a charm ... when using it in `SomeMethod()` only. I *could* theoretically implement this as I am wrapping all the methods that are called in `SomeMethod()` before exposing them to the final assembly, but I dislike this approach, because it will give my code unnessessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

When an exception is thrown, the execution flow is broken. You can catch the exception or not but you cannot "continue" after the exception is thrown.

You can split your logic into parts and continue to the next part when one throws an exception, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a way apart from an AOP approach in this case. Given that you are unable to change `SomeMethod()` or any of the methods it calls, you will need to look at adorning the called methods like `MethodThrowingInternalExceptionOrRatherContinuableError()` with an aspect that catches the 'continuable' exceptions.

The aspect would effectively wrap the method call in a `try{...} catch(InternalFrameworkException)` (or similar catchable exception) block.

As you have already noted, you are unable to drop back into a method once it has thrown an exception, even if the caller catches the exception in a `catch()` block, so you need to inject into the methods you are calling, which an AOP framework like [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net) will allow you to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved similar problem by wrapping the calls to InternalFrameworkMethod() in try-catch(InternalFrameworkException) blocks and calling it somethig like InternalFrameworkMethodSafe() and then in SomeMethod call the treated InternalFrameworkMethodSafe().

```
void InternalFrameworkMethodSafe()
{
    try
    {
        InternalFrameworkMethod();
    }
    catch(InternalFrameworkException e)
    {
        Trace.Write("error in internal method" + e);
    }
}

void SomeMethod()
{
    ...
    InternalFrameworkMethodSafe();
    ...
}
```

It may not work in your case if the internal framework is in wrong state and not able to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of throwing the error you can return the error that way the flow won't break and you will also get the error.