# Continue the try even excepted

Tags: c#, exception

A few days ago I asked a question on this site, but I think the people who shared their time to help me (thank you to them) did not really realize my point of view. Here is the link [Catch and Continue? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203262/catch-and-continue-c-sharp/45203354#45203354)

They thought I wanted to end the try-catch, and continue with the rest of the code. But I don't

That is my question but more reformed:

I want to get a try-catch, but I need the try to the end even it returns an exception. like this:

```
        // I thought a perfect example with math for this case.
        // It is possible to divide a number with negative and positive numbers
        // but it is not possible to divide a number by zero, So
        // 5/5= 1                  // ok
        // 5/4= 1.25               // ok
        // 5/3= 1.66666666667      // ok
        // 5/2= 2.5                // ok
        // 5/1= 5                  // ok
        // 5/0= Math Error // Oh, this is an error so I stop the try here.
        // 5/-1= -5                // foo
        // 5/-2= -2.5              // foo
        // 5/-3= -1.66666666667    // foo
        // 5/-4= -1.25             // foo
        // 5/-5= -1                // foo
        // foo = This is not a error, but I will not do it because the previous error
```

What I need here is to "ignore" that exception and continue try-catch (divide all positive and negative numbers by ignoring division by zero.) How can I do it?

This is just a clear example for my problem, I know someone would say to put all the "numbers" in a listbox and remove what I do not want however my original code always returns the same exception
With undefined results (both can be x as y can be).

(Is not a critical exception such as lack of memory or capacity, is a simple exception that will not make any logical problem, so there is no problem ignoring the exception)

Thank You!

Comment: Correct if its not correct understanding : you want to get out of the loop if there is an exception?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
foreach(var x = 5; x > -5; x--)
{
    try
    {
        // Do the math here
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        // Log/Print exception, just don't throw one or the loop will exit
    }
}
```

The code above will continue processing even if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
try { operation1(); } catch { }
try { operation2(); } catch { }
try { operation3(); } catch { }
...
```

As a side note, if you find yourself wanting to do this, chances are your design pattern is flawed.