# How can I Suppress and Ignore 500 codes in an API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a very simple c# Web API controller that looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet("api/GameTask/")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        // connect to 3rd party API
        var gameTask = await GamerAPI.GetGameTask();
        if (gameTask == null) return NoContent();
        return Ok(gameTask);
    }
```

This API hits another API(3rd party).

For some reason, about 40% of the time, the 3rd party API will sometimes throw a 500 Internal Server Error in the browser console.

The error doesn't actually affect the website at all.

So, for now, I want to ignore and suppress all 500 errors that this one API Get request might throw.

The problem is, the object it is getting back from the 3rd party API doesn't contain any status codes.

Is there a way that I can detect a 500 code in the controller and just suppress the error so it doesn't send the 500 code back to the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: `await GamerAPI.GetGameTask()` is the call that might throw an exception?

Comment: @gunr2171 yes, but I spent all day stepping through the code on my development machine and it won't throw any errors on development.  Just when it's on my server.  But then, it's only 35-40% of the time, not all the time.  :/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore Exception in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913159/ignore-exception-in-c-sharp) - just wrap your lines in a `try`, and leave the `catch` empty.

Comment: @gunr2171 I have never seen that before, is that something I can put into my Controller method?  Thanks!

Comment: @gunr2171 also I don't need it globally, just for this one controller

Comment: You don't need to make a method, just wrap the lines inside your method in a "try". After the catch (which you leave blank), you return what should be returned when an error occurs, likes `Ok()`.

Comment: @gunr2171 Oh ok, so just like this? `try { var gameTask = await GamerAPI.GetGameTask(); } catch { }` ?

Comment: All the lines you currently have in the method. You can't use a variable you declare inside a `try` scope outside of the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try [Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0).**

> **[Exception filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#exception-filters)** apply global policies to unhandled exceptions that
> occur before the response body has been written to.

In the following example, `SupressInternalErrorAttribute` catches all types of raised exceptions before response getting dispatched. It rewrites Response content and status regardless of what type of exception has been thrown.

```
public class SupressInternalErrorAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.Result = new ContentResult()
        {
            StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status204NoContent
        };
        base.OnException(context);
    }
}
```

The sample API is annotated via `[SupressInternalError]` attribute, besides it throws `System.DivideByZeroException` whenever the random number equals zero (plays the role of question's 3rd party).

```
    [HttpGet("api/GameTask/")]
    [SupressInternalError]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(10 / new Random().Next(0, 2));
    }
```

As a result, when random number is zero, API returns `204 NoContent` instead of `500 InternalServerError`, otherwise it returns `10` entitled with `200 OK` status.

Comment: Thanks, where would I put the `SupressInternalErrorAttribute` method?  Would that be inside my controller?  thank you sir

Comment: `SupressInternalErrorAttribute` **class**  (not method) needs to be defined somewhere accessible by your controller like other classes (maybe next to your controller). It actually depends on how much do you want to use this attribute in other controllers.

Comment: Honestly, it seems like a useful class.  So I might only need it for this one controller, but it could be useful to others as well.  So I would just create a new class file?  Then make sure to import it in, and then just use it as you say.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea to make it available for further usages. (Marking the answer as correct would be appreciated)